# ActionScript 3 change working area size

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flex3, adobe, movie

How to change working area size? I've the following code but it doesn't work


`stage.stageWidth = 200;


stage.stageHeight = 100;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to change the working area size? I don´t this you are supposed to change the stage width and height through those parameters. The SWF width and height are often set in the HTML file that contains the swf. If you want a scalable application/site I recommend you to use fullscreen flash and . Use scalemode to prevent scaleing graphics.

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

Or ... if you just want to set the default size of the SWF:

```
[SWF(frameRate="30", width="800", height="600")]
```

Answer (score 1):

try assigning your stage properties with SWF metadata tag:

```
[SWF(width="200", height="100", frameRate="32", backgroundColor="#FFFFFF")]
```